# Не срабатывает триггер при наведении на кнопку WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется "стандартный" стиль для кнопок закрыть/свернуть/развернуть:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowControlButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundGreyDarkBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8 0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Также я пытался задать триггер не через template:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowControlButton">

    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundGreyDarkBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8 0" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

И имеется отдельный стиль для кнопки "свернуть", который наследуется от вышеупомянутого "стандартного" стиля, контент для которой задается при помощи Path:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowMinimizeButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}">        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid MaxHeight="9" MaxWidth="9">
                    <Path                          
                                RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
                                Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                Stretch="None"
                                Data="M0,8 H8 M0,7 H8 M0,6 H8"
                            />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Вопрос: почему не срабатывает триггер при наведении на кнопку? Должен меняться задний фон на красный, я так понимаю это как-то связано с Path, так как если текст у самой кнопки задавать через Content, то все работает, спасибо)

Comment: Ну вы переопределили темплейт, в новом темплейте триггеров нет, чему срабатывать-то?

Comment: Изначально, триггер был задан не через template, при этом все равно не работало
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>

Comment: Ещё один баг: вы переопределили темплейт, а значение параметра Background не используете. Понятно, что после этого изменение Background не меняет отображение, ведь оно полностью определяется темплейтом.

Comment: ну изначально я задавал триггер при помощи <Style.Triggers>, и все равно не работало, по идее это же должно наследоваться в новый стиль

Comment: А вы указали наследование стилей? Если нет, наследоваться не будет.

Comment: ну параметр basedon разве не то?

Comment: Да, это то. Но вы в темплейте **не используете** Background, так что работать не будет. Используйте его.

Comment: я же унаследовал этот background, а не работает из-за path, ибо с простым content все работает

Comment: Вы унаследовали **значение свойства**, но вы перекрыли темплейт. Старый темплейт занимался отображением фона, а ваш этого не делает. Отображение фона получается не волшебным образом само собой, а прописывается в темплейте.

Answer (score 0):

Вынес Path в саму кнопку:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource WindowControlButton}">
    <Grid MaxHeight="9" MaxWidth="9">
       <Path                          
            RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
            Stroke="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
            StrokeThickness="1"
            Stretch="None"
            Data="M0,8 H8 M0,7 H8 M0,6 H8"
        />
   </Grid>
</Button>
```

Сам стиль WindowControlButton:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="WindowControlButton">

    <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundGreyDarkBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12 0" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundGreyLightBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```